# oversSrollFooter in recyclerView in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, overscroll

I am currently trying to change the colour of the blue horizontal shadow line that appears when you reach the top or bottom of a recyclerView. I tried to dig within the Android docs but could not find any tag such as list View android:overscrollFooter or android:overscrollHeader for recyclerView.

Please help me out.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I just verified that the hack on [this page](http://evendanan.net/android/branding/2013/12/09/branding-edge-effect/) still works with RecyclerView, but it's programmatic.